# How to define own list styles for ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, css, list, ckeditor, styles

Is there a way to define own list styles for ckeditor. I have found the plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/liststyle but it lets me choose only things like circle or square.

I want to define own css classes for ol or ul in my application that i can use. For example a class to define more space between list elements. the users of the editor should pick the list class via a context menu like in the nice "liststyle" plugin.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with CKEditor to add custom list styling to the `liststyle` plugin.

I added one new style (you can add more if you like) using the CSS class.

Here's how: in `liststyle.js` (after de-obfuscating) I insert my `.logo` class:

```
..........
function e(c,e){
    c.lang.liststyle.logo="My bullet"; // BBoyanov - adding 'My bullet' as title in dropdown list (in current language), otherwise it stay "empty" title
    var b=c.lang.liststyle;
........
style:"width:150px",
items:[[b.notset,""],[b.circle,"circle"],[b.disc,"disc"],[b.square,"square"], 
[b.logo,"logo"]],//BBoyanov - css class 'logo' as Bullet \,[b.logo,"logo"]\
........
commit:function(a){
  var b=this.getValue();b?a.setStyle("list-style-type",b):a.removeStyle("list-style-type");
  "logo"==b?a.setAttribute("class",'logo'):a.removeAttribute("class");//BBoyanv set 'logo' as CSS class
........
h={a:"lower-alpha",A:"upper-alpha",i:"lower-roman",I:"upper-roman", 
1:"decimal", disc:"disc", circle:"circle", square:"square",logo:"logo"};//BBoyanov \,logo:"logo"\
........
```

You define the CSS class in `ckeditor.css` (to be visualised in CKEditor) and in your own CSS file.

If you prefer different titles for different languages, you must put `translation` in the corresponding language `.js` file of CKEditor.

It worked for me.

However, probably this is injection because it takes over the `allowedContent` - need tests and confirmation.

Comment: Just small correction:
    `"logo"==b?a.setAttribute("class", b ):a.removeAttribute("class");`

Comment: You should correct your post by clicking on [edit], not by commenting on it

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed the approach mentioned above works, I am using Drupal, Ckeditor List Style (plugin) and the Ckeditor List Style module (Drupal module).

I needed to make a change to the lang > en.js file to add the appropriate Title in instead of the function as the OP.

```
    cute: 'Cute',
```

Once that was done, inside the liststyle.js file I updated the existing code to this:

Existing code in liststyle.js file:

```
                    commit: function(element) {
                        var value = this.getValue();
                        if (value)
                            element.setStyle('list-style-type', value);
                        else
                            element.removeStyle('list-style-type');
                    }
```

New code:

```
                     commit: function(element) {
                        var value = this.getValue();
                        if (value) {
                            if (value == 'cute') {
                                element.setAttribute("class", 'cute');
                                element.removeStyle('list-style-type');
                            } else {
                                element.setStyle('list-style-type', value);
                            }
                        } else {
                            element.removeStyle('list-style-type');
                        }
                     }
```